# rosjava Gradle build: Could not copy MANIFEST.MF

Tags: ros, java, rosjava, gradle

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I try to build rosjava, I am running into this very strange error:

> :rosjava_messages:jar
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an
> exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Could not copy MANIFEST.MF to
>   '/Users/Yeison/ros_java/rosjava_core/rosjava_messages/build/tmp/jar/MANIFEST.MF'.

When I listed the file, it shows the proper permissions.  The file is owned by me.  However, it contains 0 Bytes.  I even tried deleting the file and rerunning the gradle install.  The same problem persisted.

```
-rw-r--r--  1 Yeison  staff     0B Mar 25 06:45 /Users/Yeison/ros_java/rosjava_core/rosjava_messages/build/tmp/jar/MANIFEST.MF
```

Is something creating the file prematurely?  I'll take a look to see if I can find that.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59105/rosjava-gradle-build:-could-not-copy-manifest.mf/) by [Yeison Rodriguez](https://answers.ros.org/users/4057/yeison-rodriguez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2013-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This problem can be resolved by making sure that the setup.bash file is sourced.  I accidentally opened a new terminal and forgot to re-source.

---

Originally posted by [Yeison Rodriguez](https://answers.ros.org/users/4057/yeison-rodriguez/) with karma: 103 on 2013-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0